# How to make non-member function from one file friend with class in other file?

Tags: c++, friend

Lets say I have one file

// X.h (first file)

```
#include <iostream>
class X{
    int x;
public:
    X(int i);
    void print_me();
};
```

// X.cpp (second file)

```
#include "X.h"
X::X(int i){x = i}

void X::print_me(){std::cout<< x << endl;}
```

// main.cpp (third file)

```
#include "X.h"

void swap(int lhs, int rhs){
  // do the swap
}

class Y{
   X x_obj;
public: 
    friend void swap(Y& lhs, Y& rhs){
        swap(lhs.x_obj.x, rhs.x_obj.x);
    }

};
int main(){return 0;}
```

My question is:
  How can I make class Y in main.cpp a friend of X?

I was thinking of breaking class Y into .h and .cpp file and including Y.h file into X.h and go from there. Is there any way other then that. I mean in the current condition of the code to make Y a friend of X:

The error I am getting in current condition is :

```
> In file included from main.cpp:1:0: X.h: In function 'void swap(Y&,
> Y&)': X.h:3:9: error: 'int X::x' is private
>      int x;
>          ^ main.cpp:12:24: error: within this context
>          swap(lhs.x_obj.x, rhs.x_obj.x);
>                         ^ In file included from main.cpp:1:0: X.h:3:9: error: 'int X::x' is private
>      int x;
>          ^ main.cpp:12:37: error: within this context
>          swap(lhs.x_obj.x, rhs.x_obj.x);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> My question is: How can I make class Y in main.cpp a friend of X?

Making `Y` the friend of `X` won't solve this issue. You need to make the function `swap()` friend of class `X` since it's trying to access the private members of `X`.

```
class Y; // forward declaration to avoid circular dependencies
class X{
    friend void swap(Y& lhs, Y& rhs);
    ...
};
```

Note you should use forward declaration to avoid including `Y.h` into `X.h`, which leads to [circular dependency issue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_dependency).

Comment: Now I face new problem of non member fuction void swap(Y& lhs, Y& rhs) accessing private member of Y which is  X x_obj since this function tries to access the private member of Y.

Comment: @solti You've declared it as the friend of class `Y`, isn't it?

Comment: yup .. for some reason I thought declaring friend multiple times create problem .. but apparently it does not .. after placing  friend void swap(Y& lhs, Y& rhs); in Y as I had did earlier it worked

Comment: @solti Sure it's fine, you can declare it as many class' friend.

Comment: just curious about placing class Y; inside X.h without the header file. How does the compiler know what Y is .. I read some where pointer and reference are fine .. other then that I might have compilation error

Comment: @solti Declaring function parameters as pointer or reference don't need a complete class type. So the forward declaration is allowed here. See [Incomplete type](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type#Incomplete_type).

Comment: thank you that was the exact term I was looking for.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117394/discussion-between-solti-and-songyuanyao).